# How does the new fee market structure from the v1.10.25 individual throughput for any one "bucket"

Tags: fees

From the new gas market structure first proposed here (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/23211) we can see that transactions per protocol will be sorted into "buckets" and once one bucket is "filled", other buckets will be processed by the current leader.

My question is, how "large" are these buckets? Are we essentially capping the number of transactions that can be processed per protocol per block? I'm trying to understand how this impacts the current true throughput of the network.

As a follow-up, what's the trade-off here? How does localizing gas fees impact network performance?